# Transparent button without edge

Tags: vaadin-flow

I need to create a button transparent and without any edge in Vaadin 23.
I didn't find any LUMO style to apply such properties
Which kind of style should I apply ?
Tks

Comment: Check the docs: https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/button/styling

Answer (score 1):

Check these two `Button` variant styles, which one is better in your application?

```
    button1.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.TERTIARY);
    button2.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.TERTIARY_INLINE);
```